# Partial class with single part / No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform, partial-classes

I'm trying to implement a simple partial class and method in a shared project in a Forms app, to work with Android and iOs projects.

All classes have the same namespace (*sharedTest*)and have the keyword partial, but the partial classes and methods in the Android and iOs files seem to not recognise the other part implemented in the Shared code.

The partial class *Shared* says "partial class with single part"

The method *PlatformGetFilePath* in the Android and iOs files throws the error "No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method"

The variable *_filepath*  in the Android and iOs file throws "does not exist in the current method"

is there anything that I am missing to make this work?

Partial class in the Shared project:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace sharedTest
{
    public partial class Shared
    {
        public Shared()
        {

        }

        partial void PlatformGetFilePath(string filename);
        string _filepath;
        public string GetFilePath(string filename)
        {
            PlatformGetFilePath(filename);
            return _filepath;
        }

    }
}
```

Android:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace sharedTest
{
    public partial class Shared
    {
        partial void PlatformGetFilePath(string filename)
        {

           string libraryPath=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); ;

            _filepath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

iOs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace sharedTest
{
    public partial class Shared 
    {
        partial void PlatformGetFilePath(string filename)
        {

            string documentsPath=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
            string libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library");

            _filepath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it will not work because you can use the same namespace in both iOS and Android.If you want to do different things in iOS and Android,you can use `Custom Renderers` or `DependencyService` .For example

> in Forms

```
...

namespace sharedTest
{

 public class MyClass
  {
    public interface IGetFilePath
    {
        String PlatformGetFilePath(string filename);
    }
  }

}
```

> in iOS

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using sharedTest;//your xamarin.forms name
using sharedTest.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyiOSClass))]

namespace sharedTest.iOS
{
    public class MyiOSClass:MyClass.IGetFilePath
    {
        public MyiOSClass()
        {

        }
        public string PlatformGetFilePath(string filename)
        {

         string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
         string libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library");

         string filepath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, filename);

         return filepath;
        }
    }
}
```

> in Android

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using sharedTest;//your xamarin.forms name
using sharedTest.Droid;
using System.IO;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyAndroidClass)) ]

namespace sharedTest.Droid 
{
    public class MyAndroidClass: MyClass.IGetFilePath
    {
        public MyAndroidClass()
        {

        }

        public string PlatformGetFilePath(string filename)
       {

         string libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); ;

         string filepath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, filename);

         return filepath; 
       }
   }
}
```

> Implementing in Shared Code

```
var filePath = DependencyService.Get<MyClass.IGetFilePath>().PlatformGetFilePath("your file name");
```

For more information you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done - but the shared portion of the partial class needs to be defined in a "Shared Project" project type.

I made the mistake of thinking that this "Shared Project" could be my Xamarin Forms .net standard class library. It couldn't - the words "Shared Project" are referring to an actual project type called "Shared Project" - not just to a project that is shared.

You need to add a new project of the type "Shared Project" then reference that from both your Xamarin Forms class library AND your platform specific project. And also make sure the namespaces match as you have done.